# How to include an Eloquent relationship into JSON conversion result?

Tags: php, json, laravel, eloquent

I want to return JSON data to my Angular front-end with Laravel 5 but I am stuck with this problem : I have an **Alert** eloquent model which has a relationship with **AlertFrequency** model:

```
class Alert extends Model
{
    public function alertFrequency()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\AlertFrequency');
    }
}
```

but when I try to return the alerts listing as a JSON...

```
$alerts = Auth::user()->alerts->toJson();

return $alerts;
```

here is what I get :

```
[{"id":9,"title":"fqdsgsq","place":"gdqsgq","user_id":1,"alert_frequency_id":3,"job_naming_id":3,"created_at":"2016-07-16 14:09:41","updated_at":"2016-07-16 14:09:41"}]
```

So I do have the "alert_frequency_id" column value but not the actual **AlertFrequency** object

The only workaround I found to be working so far is this :

```
$alerts = Auth::user()->alerts;

foreach ($alerts as $alert) {
    $alert->jobNaming = $alert->jobNaming;
    $alert->alertFrequency = $alert->alertFrequency;
}

return $alerts;
```

which is very ugly...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to manually load the relationship. This is called [lazy eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations) a relationship.

```php
$alerts = Auth::user()->alerts->load('alertFrequency')->toJson();
return $alerts;
```

When you do `Auth::user()->alerts->toJson()` you just fetched the data from the Alert model, but you want data from another model (another table) then you need to tell that using the `load` method.

#### Bonus

If your code is in a controller method or a router closure instead of calling `toJson()` you can just return the collection and Laravel will do that for you. Example:

```php
public function controllerMethod() {
    return Auth::user()->alerts->load('alertFrequency');
}
```

Happy coding!

Comment: Dude, you just saved my life. I've read about "Nested Eager Loading", it's just amazing. I didn't know about this L5 function. It's getting better and better to work with Laravel, I'm fallen in love about this framework.